# HttpServletRequest#login() not working in Java

Tags: java, servlets, j-security-check

`j_security_check` just doesn't seem enough for me to perform login process. So, instead of submitting the form to j_security_check i created my own servlet and in that i am programmatically trying to do login. This works but i am not able to redirect to my restricted resource. Can anybody tell me what can be the problem? This is `processRequest` method of my servlet :-

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            String strUsername = request.getParameter("txtusername");
            String strPassword = request.getParameter("txtpassword");
            if(strUsername == null || strPassword == null || strUsername.equals("") || strPassword.equals(""))
                throw new Exception("Username and/or password missing.");
            request.login(strUsername, strPassword);
            System.out.println("Login succeeded!!");

            if(request.isUserInRole(ROLES.ADMIN.getValue())){//enum
                System.out.println("Found in Admin Role");
                response.sendRedirect("/app/Admin/home.jsf");

            }
            else if (request.isUserInRole(ROLES.GENERAL.getValue()))
                response.sendRedirect("/app/Common/index.jsf");
            else //guard
                throw new Exception("No role for user " + request.getRemoteUser());


        }catch(Exception ex){
            //patch work why there needs to be blogger here?
            System.out.println("Invalid username and/or password!!");
            response.sendRedirect("/app/Common/index.jsf");
        }finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine and i can even see message "Found in Admin Role" but problem is even after authenticating i am not able to redirect my request to some other page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure but i think this issue is the subject of

https://glassfish.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=11340

Comment: if you are using glassfish you can try com.sun.appserv.security.ProgrammaticLogin to do the login process
(available in security.jar in <GF-DOMAIN-DIR>/modules directory)

Answer (score 0):

Remove those lines, they doesn't belong there:

```
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

and

```
        out.close();
```

If you close the `OutputStream`, the redirect cannot be taken place. You should in fact have seen an `IllegalStateException: Response already committed` in the server logs.

Comment: Hi BalusC,
Removing those three lines doesn't help still. It still doesn't redirect me. Here is what i get in Glassfish Admin Console :-

FINE: [Web-Security] Checking Web Permission with Principals : nitesh, Admin
FINE: [Web-Security] Web Permission = (javax.security.jacc.WebRoleRefPermission AuthenticationCheck Admin)
FINE: [Web-Security] hasRoleRef perm: (javax.security.jacc.WebRoleRefPermission AuthenticationCheck Admin)
FINE: [Web-Security] hasRoleRef isGranted: true
INFO: Found in Admin Role

Comment: FINE: SecurityContext: setCurrentSecurityContext method called
FINE: [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: Blogger/Blogger
FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission perm: (javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission /Admin/home.xhtml GET)
FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission isGranted: true
FINE: [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: Blogger/Blogger
FINE: [Web-Security] Generating a protection domain for Permission check.
FINE: [Web-Security] Codesource with Web URL: file:/Blogger/Blogger
FINE: [Web-Security] Checking Web Permission with Principals : null

Comment: FINE: [Web-Security] Web Permission = (javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission /Admin/home.xhtml GET)
FINE: [Web-Security] hasResource isGranted: false
FINE: [Web-Security] hasResource perm: (javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission /Admin/home.xhtml GET)
FINE: [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: Blogger/Blogger
FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission perm: (javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission /Common/index.jsf GET)
FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission isGranted: true

Please help me BalusC!!

Comment: What exactly happens instead of the redirect? Isn't there some filter blocking/changing the request?

Comment: No BalusC,
There are no filters. The same form when i submit to j_security_check works great. But for HttpServletRequest#login it doens't.

I just have normal constraints(in login config) in web.xml and configured it to have form based login. Besides that, there are no filters or anything. Am i doing right? Can HttpServletRequest#login actually replace j_security_check? If so, then why is it not working? Any idea?

Comment: Please have a look at the log above and specially this line in 2nd comment :
Checking Web Permission with Principals : null
Once i get princpial with nitesh,Admin why does it again become null?

I am just guessing that may be HttpServletRequest#login is only for a particular request? and not for complete session. That's why once the principal becomes nitesh,Admin and then when i redirect the principals are found to be null and so it throws me to login page again.